# Recursive AsString() to print STL containers in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write an AsString() function that converts STL containers to string according to my taste. Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
template<class T>
inline string AsString(const T& v);

template<class First, class Second>
inline string AsString(const pair<First, Second>& p);

template<class Iter>
inline string PrintSequence(const char* delimiters, Iter begin, Iter end) {
  string result;
  result += delimiters[0];
  int size = 0;
  for (size = 0; begin != end; ++size, ++begin) {
    if (size > 0) {
      result += ", ";
    }
    result += AsString(*begin);
  }
  result += delimiters[1];
  result += StringPrintf("<%d>", size);
  return result;
}

#define OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence) \
template<class T1, class T2> \
inline string AsString(const Sequence<T1, T2>& seq) { \
  return PrintSequence("[]", seq.begin(), seq.end()); \
}

OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(vector)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(deque)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(list)

template<class First, class Second>
inline string AsString(const pair<First, Second>& p) {
  return "(" + AsString(p.first) + ", " + AsString(p.second) + ")";
}

template<class T>
inline string AsString(const T& v) {
  ostringstream s;
  s << v;
  return s.str();
}
```

As you can see, the basic idea is that `AsString()` recursively calls itself on STL containers and then it bottoms out to the usual `operator<<()` (the reason I don't want to override `operator<<()` is because I don't want to interfere with other libraries that do exactly that).

Now, `AsString()` compiles and works on shallow containers, but not on nested ones:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
AsString(v) == "[1, 2]<2>";  // true

vector<vector<int> > m;
m.push_back(v);
m.push_back(v);
AsString(m) == "[[1, 2]<2>, [1, 2]<2>]<2>";  // Compilation Error!!!
```

The compiler, for some reason, wants to use `operator<<()` when trying to print the elements of `m', despite the fact that I have provided a template specialization for vectors.

How could I make `AsString()` work?

**UPDATE**: OK, turns out the order of definitions do matter (at least for this compiler -- gcc 4.4.3). When I put the macro definitions first, the compiler will correctly pick them up and display a vector of vectors. Inexplicable.

Comment: Minor remark: I'd put the size before the container rather than after, it would make reparsing easier. Otherwise neat code (just remove the `inline` on template functions, it's unnecessary).

Answer (score 3):

The template world is wonderful... and a real trap to the unwary...

A specialization, is taking an existing template function and specifying all its arguments.

An overload is reusing the same name that another function (whether template or not) for a different set of arguments.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T const& t);

template <>
void foo<int>(int i); // this is a "complete" specialization

template <typename T, typename U>
void foo<std::pair<T,U>>(std::pair<T,U> const& pair);
  // this is a "partial" specialization
  // and by the way... it does NOT COMPILE

template <typename T, typename U>
void foo(std::pair<T,U> const& pair); // this is an overload
```

Note the syntactical difference, in the overload there is no `<xxxx>` after the identifier (`foo` here).

It is not possible, in C++, to partially specialize a function; that is to leave some genericity in the arguments. You can either overload or fully specialize: mandatory reading at this point [GotW #49: Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)

Therefore, the choice is between:

```
template <typename T>
std::string AsString(const T& v); // (1)

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
std::string AsString(std::vector<T, Allocator> const& v); // (2)
```

And the real question is: what is the type of `*begin` ?

Well, `m` is not const-qualified:

- `Iter` logically is `std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator`.
- the type of `*begin` is thus `std::vector<int>&`

So the two overloads are considered with:

- (1): `T = std::vector<int>`, requires a conversion to const-ref
- (2): `T = int, U = std::allocator<int>`, requires a conversion to const-ref

The second should be selected because it's closer to the real type, as far as I understand. I tested it with VC++ 2010 and it actually got selected.

Could you also declare a non-const qualified version of the vector overload and see if it appeases your compiler ? (which I'd like to know the name of, by the way ;) ).

Comment: That sounds about right, and it's a bug in the ADL in the compiler the OP is using.  I was, naturally, hesitant to suggest a compiler bug as the reason, but I do know pre-2010 and other compilers have bugs with templates in this area.

Comment: @Fred: yes, besides ADL template and overload resolution is usually brittle, which doesn't surprise me given the set of rules that cover this... and it only got worse with rvalue references and variadic templates (argh). I don't even trust myself any longer to predict which function could get selected :/

Comment: It's gcc-4.4.3-glibc-2.11.1. By the way, do you think declaration order has to do anything with it?

Comment: @Lajos: I don't know, as I said in the previous comment I'm really murky now with all the rules there are in the standard. It wasn't easy before, but it's hellish now :/

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a specialization, you have *overloaded* AsString.  As it happens, your later overload isn't preferred over the T const& version.

Instead, [overload op<< in a special namespace](http://ideone.com/4HNYy) for the various stdlib containers.  The namespace is important so you don't affect other code, but you will explicitly use it in AsString:

```
namespace make_sure_to_put_these_overloads_in_a_namespace {

// Your PrintSequence adapted to a stream instead of a string:
template<class Iter>
void PrintSequence(std::ostream &s, const char* delim,
                   Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  s << delim[0];
  int size = 0;
  if (begin != end) {
    s << *begin;
    ++size;
    while (++begin != end) {
      s << ", " << *begin;
      ++size;
    }
  }
  s << delim[1] << '<' << size << '>';
}

#define OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence) \
template<class T1, class T2> \
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, Sequence<T1, T2> const &seq) { \
  PrintSequence(s, "[]", seq.begin(), seq.end()); \
  return s; \
}

OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::vector)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::deque)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::list)
// other types
#undef OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER

template<class First, class Second>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, std::pair<First, Second> const &p) { \
  s << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
  return s;
}

}

template<class T>
std::string AsString(T const &v) {
  using namespace make_sure_to_put_these_overloads_in_a_namespace;
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << v;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer. You see, I don't want to get into the namespace resolution business when it comes to operator overloading because it makes my head spin. Is it possible to solve this problem without introducing a new namespace? Also, is it possible to do it without overloading `operator<<()`?

Comment: @LajosNagy: This is the easiest solution.  If you have questions about what you don't understand about this answer, I'd be happy to address them.

Comment: OK, here's what I don't understand. What do you mean I didn't _specialize_ but rather I _overloaded_ `AsString()`. Why would `AsString()` work on shallow containers (like in the example) but not on nested ones? What makes the compiler pick `AsString()` for the shallow vector, but not for the elements of the nested vector?

Comment: @LajosNagy: I'm missing something about how the overload resolution is failing for a vector of vectors but not for a vector of ints in your code, but I do know that you have overloaded AsString.  Remember, first of all, that you *can't* partially specialize functions in current C++.  Yes, I did try my solution, and it works: link included in my answer.

Comment: Did you try it with an `operator<<()` for vectors already in scope in the root namespace? I'm getting "ambiguous overload" when I try to use the `AsString()` you provided.

Comment: @LajosNagy: In my solution, you don't overload AsString.  And don't put the op<< overload for vector in the root namespace.